# HTTPS Warning and Certificate Error when Updating Network

Tags: multisite, upgrade, ssl, network-admin

Is there a workaround for this error?

> Warning! Problem updating https://[host]/[blabla]. Your server may not be able to connect to sites running on it.
>   Error message: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Is there a way to disable it just for the upgrade? I don't see a point for peer authentication just for the updates, unless I'm getting this wrong.

Comment: Unless you are referring to a MultiSite Network, this isn't a question for this site.

Comment: @ckpepper02 multisite is part of WordPress core (been for a while) and is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure if the OP was referring to Multisite or not. Language sounded like they could have been talking about a server.

Comment: it is a multisite, sorry if placed it wrongly.